# Pandas sum with groupby on condition

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have this dataframe:

```
    id  priority    quantity
0   A   1           2
1   A   2           4
2   A   3           4
3   A   4           2
4   B   1           5
5   B   2           7
6   B   3           2
7   B   4           3
```

that I want to turn into this one:

```
    id  priority    quantity cumulativeQuantity
0   A   1           2        2
1   A   2           4        6
2   A   3           4        10
3   A   4           2        12
4   B   1           5        5
5   B   2           7        12
6   B   3           2        14
7   B   4           3        17
```

Columns `id`, `priority` and `quantity` haven't changed.

`cumulativeQuantity` is the sum, by `id`, of all `quantity` from 1 to n where n is the `priority` of the current row.

`priority` can take any value. Only orders matter. We sum if priority is lower than the priority of the current row.

**ANSWER:**

```
df.groupby(['id','priority']).sum().groupby(level=0).cumsum().reset_index()
```

Comment: groupby + cumsum